# How to extract string data from script tag, where script doesn't have any id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

```
<script>window.extractKey = 'value'</script>
```

I have to extract value of **window.extractKey** which is present in my html source code.

*P.S.- I have to extract the value using javascript methods.*

Answer (score 1):

All script tags on a page have, and modify, the same `window`. It works fine:

```html
<script>
  window.extractKey = 'value'
</script>

<script>
  const res = window.extractKey;
  console.log(res);
</script>
```

Comment: I have to extract the value using javascript methods.

Comment: But why? There's literally no requirement to do so - it'll be available in any other script tag. You could select all tags, iterate through until you find one assigning that value, but...

Comment: I have a separate html file and I need to perform operation on that file and need to extract that value. That's why I need this using javascript method.